# Node.js web scrapper after logging in to portal

Tags: node.js, authentication, web-scraping, logging

I want to get some data from (https://booksy.com/pro/en-pl/onboarding/Login) but to do this its necessary to log in. I have my credientials but the service doesn't provide an open API.
Is that even possible to scrap some data after logging into the service using node.js?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible. You may need more than NodeJs something like scriptable Headless browser : https://phantomjs.org/